# WebStorm shortcut to wrap/surround selection?

Tags: webstorm

Often in coding and templating I need to wrap a certain part of text. Is there any shortcut to wrap the current selection in WebStorm?

For example:

```
camel
//to
"camel"
```

or:

```
var x = 8;

//to
function(){
var x = 8;
}
```

I tried to use Using Surround Templates by `Ctrl+Alt+J` but I get the answer "No surround templates defined in this context".

I am using in WebStorm 2016.2.4

Comment: Just create some in the Settings. Search Live Templates in the Settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> camel
>   //to
>   "camel"

Such surrounding can be enabled in settings (if it's not enabled in your):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Surround selection on typing quote or brace`

[image]

---

> var x = 8;
>
> //to
>   function(){
>   var x = 8;
>   }

Live Template is the way to go. Make sure that you use `$SELECTION$` to denote selected text -- it's the **key hint** for IDE -- it tells that this is "Surround With" kind of Live Template.

This is covered in:

- [Official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)
- [Tutorial article](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm#LiveTemplates(Snippets)inPhpStorm-CreatingSurroundTemplates)

So your Live Template should look something like this:

```
function(){
    $SELECTION$
}
```